# Timegrouper of Timegrouper

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Hi I have the following Timegrouper dataframe where the maximum value is calculated for every quarter of an hour from data that was separated per minute:

```
in: 
newdf2 = newdf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='15T')).max().fillna(0)
Out:

                         Count
time                    
2016-04-20 05:30:00        4.0
2016-04-20 05:45:00        0.0
2016-04-20 06:00:00        0.0
2016-04-20 06:15:00        6.0
2016-04-20 06:30:00        5.0
```

I would like this to go back to minutes like this:

```
                         Count
time                    
2016-04-20 05:31:00        4.0
2016-04-20 05:32:00        4.0
2016-04-20 05:33:00        4.0
2016-04-20 05:34:00        4.0
2016-04-20 05:35:00        4.0
...
2016-04-20 05:44:00        4.0
2016-04-20 05:45:00        0.0
```

I tried to do the timegrouper again with interval= '1T' but this returns nothing.

Can i achieve this by a simple pandas function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html):

```
df = df.resample('1T').ffill()
print (df)
                     Count
time                      
2016-04-20 05:30:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:31:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:32:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:33:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:34:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:35:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:36:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:37:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:38:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:39:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:40:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:41:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:42:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:43:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:44:00    4.0
2016-04-20 05:45:00    0.0
2016-04-20 05:46:00    0.0
...
...
```

Comment: Jezrael, thank you very much! This makes my code a lot easier in other parts of the code aswel.

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!